# Mongo query - fetch records not exactly matches with specified values in filter list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I tried around a bit, but I couldn't find the way to do this with same specific set of elements.

I have the following documents in db,

```
{
  sys_cd : ["A","B"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["A", "S"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["A","B","S"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["A"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["B","S"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["S"]
}
```

I would like a query that returns only the following  records, any doc that contains values other than A, B , A & B should return

```
{
  sys_cd : ["A", "S"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["A","B","S"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["B","S"]
},
{
  sys_cd : ["S"]
}
```

I tried with element match but it's not working.. is there a way to achieve this? Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let inputArray = ["A", "B"]; // or ["B", "A"]

db.myCollection.find({
    sys_cd: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $nin: inputArray
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator, and add list of arrays,

```
db.collection.find({
  sys_cd: {
    $nin: [
      ["A"],
      ["B"],
      ["A", "B"]
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RBpHTBz1wvC)

Comment: Hi Vishal gr8 answer but what about the scenario `["B", "A"]`?  Input array reverse?

Comment: i think its better to generate both possibility in client side and pass in `$nin`.